# How to XSLT-Transform a XHTML-Dokument with IE-conditional-comments?

Tags: xml, internet-explorer, xslt, xhtml, conditional-comments

I transform a XHTML dokument to another XML-Dokument with XSLT.
In the XHTML-Input-Dokument there are several IE-conditional-comments, like this one:

```
<!--[if lte IE 7]>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='ie.css' type='text/css' />
<![endif]-->
```

But while the transformation they get lost...
Even if I try only to do an identity-copy:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" />

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I only get the link-element without the conditional comment around it.

How can I copy the XHTML-Dokument with the conditional comment?

Comment: *I only get the link-element without the conditional comment around it.* - I doubt that. To XSLT, the *whole thing* is a comment, it would not copy only part of it.

Comment: Your error lies elsewhere and not in the code you posted. @Tomalak has right.

Answer (score 2):

> Even if I try only to do an identity-copy:
>
> ...
>
> I only get the
>   link-element without the conditional comment around it.

**If this is true, which I doubt, then you are using a very buggy XSLT processor**. No compliant XSLT processor will strip out a comment and produce the comment text -- without having the appropriate XSLT instructions (within a template matching `comment()`).

**Of course, I couldn't reproduce this "problem"** having tried 6-7 different XSLT processors with this transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on this XML document** (the comment, wrapped in a single top element to become a well-formed XML document):

```
<html>
<!--[if lte IE 7]> <link rel='stylesheet' href='ie.css' type='text/css' /> <![endif]-->
</html>
```

**the result is exactly the same XML document**:

```
<html>
  <!--[if lte IE 7]> <link rel='stylesheet' href='ie.css' type='text/css' /> <![endif]-->
</html>
```

**Having said that, to generate such a "comment" is a little bit more tricky** -- here is a demo how to do this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <html>
       <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&#xA;&lt;!--[if lte IE 7]> </xsl:text>
       <link rel='stylesheet' href='ie.css' type='text/css' />
       <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"> &lt;![endif]-->&#xA;</xsl:text>
     </html>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied to any XML document (not used in our example), the wanted, correct output is produced**:

```
<html>
<!--[if lte IE 7]> <link rel="stylesheet" href="ie.css" type="text/css"/> <![endif]-->
</html>
```